# FAQ: Practical questions?

Tags: feature-request

Today, I decided to click the "new on puzzling" banner and then on the first question just out of curiosity: [What questions should I avoid asking?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) That page contains the following text:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Er... no?

I know puzzling is the odd one out here, but this would seem to be flat-out wrong if you ask me. Can this be removed?

Comment: +1 Never noticed that though.

Comment: This is one of those site-wide things that may not be changeable.

Comment: @Emrakul I would have said "I guess that makes it a feature request, then", but you already added the tag, so that's already clear.

Comment: @Emrakul Pretty sure it is changeable, if we get a clear consensus on what it should be changed to and then bug some CMs. I think [codegolf.se] has made lots of changes of this kind, after having been [proactive and organised](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8350/52442) about working out exactly what changes they need/want.

Comment: @randal'thor PPCG has the same text [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)